# Bash script, find command, using wildcards or regex

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I am writing a bash script that goes over all files in certain directory and:

1. Picks the files with names that match a specified pattern
2. Sorts them by data and time (date and time are part of the filename)
3. Takes X oldest files
4. Performs certain operations on them

The pattern used to match the files is passed to the script and looks like:

```
someprefix_[cats|dogs]_[oranges|apples|tomatos]_[2|3]*.txt
```

I tried to implement it as following (fields 6 and 7 at the pattern are assumed to contain date and time):

```
FILES=`find . -name "$PATTERN” | sort -t_ -k6 | head -n $NUM_OF_FILES`
```

It doesn't work.
Tried various options with `-name` and `-regex`....
Most examples online are for much less complicated patterns.
Since there might be hundreds of thousands of files to go through, I am looking for a solution that works efficiently.
I would like to avoid using sed for readability reasons.

Comment: Does `echo someprefix_[cats|dogs]_[oranges|apples|tomatos]_[2|3]*.txt` produce the list of files that you want to sort?

Comment: @TomFenech It doesn't, but the following works with ls: ls someprefix_{cats,dogs}_{oranges,apples,tomatos}_[2-3]*.txt. However it doesn't work with find and sort gives an error when applied on the result of ls.

Comment: This might help: `"` != `”`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Comment: What do you think `[cats|dogs]` means in a regexp? How about in a globbing pattern? I don't think either is what you want it to mean. So figure out how to write what you want in either language and then how to call find using an expression written in that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find` regex must match the **entire path** returned by find. For example if you are searching `somedir/` for your files, then your regex must match, e.g.

```
somedir/prefix_cats_apples_2.txt
```

Complicating the picture, is you have multiple types of regex you can use by changing the `-regextype` option to `find`, e.g. `emacs (default), posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep, posix-extended`. (`posix-basic` has no alteration capability)

`posix-egrep` is probably the most transferable between your tools like `grep, sed, find, etc..` A `posix-egrep` regex for your pattern searching for the files in `somedir/` would be:

```
'somedir/prefix_(cats|dogs)_(apples|oranges|tomatos).*[23].*$'
```

Matching against a test with your filenames (with the ending number ranging `0-3` to show the exclusion of files ending in `0, 1`) the following example files were used:

```
$ls -1 somedir/
prefix_cats_apples_0.txt
prefix_cats_apples_1.txt
prefix_cats_apples_2.txt
prefix_cats_apples_3.txt
prefix_cats_oranges_0.txt
prefix_cats_oranges_1.txt
prefix_cats_oranges_2.txt
prefix_cats_oranges_3.txt
prefix_cats_tomatos_0.txt
prefix_cats_tomatos_1.txt
prefix_cats_tomatos_2.txt
prefix_cats_tomatos_3.txt
prefix_dogs_apples_0.txt
prefix_dogs_apples_1.txt
prefix_dogs_apples_2.txt
prefix_dogs_apples_3.txt
prefix_dogs_oranges_0.txt
prefix_dogs_oranges_1.txt
prefix_dogs_oranges_2.txt
prefix_dogs_oranges_3.txt
prefix_dogs_tomatos_0.txt
prefix_dogs_tomatos_1.txt
prefix_dogs_tomatos_2.txt
prefix_dogs_tomatos_3.txt
```

Now matching only files that satisfy your criteria and passing for a general `sort` would yield:

```
$ find somedir/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex 'somedir/prefix_(cats|dogs)_(apples|oranges|tomatos).*[23].*$' | sort
somedir/prefix_cats_apples_2.txt
somedir/prefix_cats_apples_3.txt
somedir/prefix_cats_oranges_2.txt
somedir/prefix_cats_oranges_3.txt
somedir/prefix_cats_tomatos_2.txt
somedir/prefix_cats_tomatos_3.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_apples_2.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_apples_3.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_oranges_2.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_oranges_3.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_tomatos_2.txt
somedir/prefix_dogs_tomatos_3.txt
```

Since you didn't provide an example of where the time/date was in the filenames, the sorting by time/date is left to you. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Works like a charm. I appreciate your detailed answer, it helped me a lot. Special thanks for your friendly attitude :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- your sorting/filtering logic is OK
- you do not require a recursive search
- you have no newlines in your filenames

I would use this:

```
printf '%s\n' someprefix_{cats,dogs}_{oranges,apples,tomatos}_[23]*.txt \
    | sort -t_ -k6 \
    | head -n $NUM_OF_FILES
```

This uses the shell's built-in glob expansion capability to generate the list of files. Each result is printed on a separate line. The output is processed using the same pipeline as in your question.

Comment: This one unfortunately didn't work for me. It returns all possible combinations of the values (cats_oranges_[23], dogs_oranges_[23], etc). I do appreciate you attempt to help.

Comment: That is because the pattern isn't matching the files - I guess that you are maybe in the wrong directory when you run the script.

Answer (score -1):

the default type of regex that matches with the find function are the Emacs regex so the notation for the patterns vary a bit.

If I understood your pattern correctly, here is the matching command that works:

```
find . '.*_\(cats\|dogs\)_\(oranges\|apples\|tomatos\)_\(2\|3\).*\.txt'
```

You can find any information you need about regex types and syntax for emacs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html).

Hope that helped

Comment: Calling this Emacs regex is highly misleading. Emacs regex has many features which are not supported by `find`, and the dialect supported by `find` is supported by many tools which are not Emacs. But no sensible regex dialect or wildcard system uses square brackets like the OP tried to use them.

Comment: @Romain I tried it, unfortunately couldn't make it work. It returns all the files in the directory, even those that don't match the pattern at all (like text12.txt). Appreciate you trying to help. I will read a bit about emacs regex.

Comment: @tripleee I agree that my usage of square brackets seems wrong.  I would appreciate help understanding how to write it correctly.

Comment: [The Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) covers a number of common beginner FAQs and has a solid section with learning resources.

Comment: Weird, I tried it on my own files and it worked.. I must've had the wrong pattern! Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Anyway, `find` doesn't acoept a regex argument outside of a predicate. You might get this to work with `-regex` but I'm pretty sure this is untested and quite possibly contains additional errors. It probably "worked" if the files happened to exist in the current directory, and/or you didn't have any files which were not supposed to match.